# Looping through HTML table and adding to database

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web page that users input information. this info is added to a summary table (ElementById('ws_tbl')).

once they have completed they press submit and the idea is the table is sent to the database.
the button calls the below which successfully loops through the tables and for each row assigns the 3 variables required for database submission.

I have to do this 1 row at a time as what the user actually passes is 3 variables that the database procude uses to get a single unique id from a large table.

```
function insert_activity(){
    var table = document.getElementById('ws_tbl');
    for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);            
        }

        var primary = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML;
        var secondary = table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML;
        var tertiary = table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML;

        insert_activity(primary, secondary, tertiary);
    }
}
```

so insert_activity() is an external php function. Ive seen examples like the below that can achieve what im asking but i cant seem to modify to include variables.

https://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3671533.htm

any help would be much appreciated as its driving me insane.

thanks

Comment: you have a javascript function and a php function with the same name?  and you want the javascript one (which runs on the client) to call the php one (which runs on the server)?

Comment: You can only run PHP code my making a request to the server. This is usually done using AJAX, a simple example is `fetch("my_api.php?action=insert&primary=what&secondary=ever");` It's like ordering a pizza basically; PHP is a guy putting stuff on the pizza and sending it out; once the pizza is in your kitchen and JavaScript starts to run, there's no way you can give orders to the cook without ordering a new pizza.

Comment: thanks for the guidance - with a little reading around ajax ive got this working.